# Sanitize URLS along with the get parameter in Drupal 6

Tags: javascript

There exists an URL https://example.com/en/recent?page=4", which displays the Drupal page correctly.

And then an end user appends onload="prompt('XSS')"name=" to the URL.
The URL now becomes https://example.com/en/recent?page=4"onload="prompt('XSS')"name="

This URL now executes the javascript and displays the prompt.

How to avoid this.Does there exist any configuration or a module or a patch?
Are there any server specific (Apache) configurations?
Need a solution that will be applicable to all the Drupal pages.

Comment: Which module provides the /en/recent route for you?

Comment: @cilefen: the /en/recent is just an example.